# Unregistering On-Execute Action on a Confirm Dialog in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dialog, dojo

I have a dojo widget as below:

```
define("myWidget/AnExperiment", [
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/dom-style",
    "dijit/ConfirmDialog",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase"
    ], function(declare, domStyle, ConfirmDialog, _WidgetBase) {

return declare([_WidgetBase], {

myDialog: null,

createDialog: function() {
self = this;

self.myDialog = new ConfirmDialog({
                title: 'MyDialog',
                content: 'This is my Dialog.',
                closable: false
            });

domStyle.set(myDialog.cancelButton.domNode, "display", "none");

self.myDialog.on("execute", function() {
                console.log('Func1 called');
                self.myFunc1();
            });

self.myDialog.show();

setTimeout(function() {
                self.changeDialogAction();
            }, 30000);

}

changeDialogAction: function () {
    var self = this;
    self.myDialog.set("title", 'Changed MyDialog');
    self.myDialog.set("content", 'This is the changed dialog');
    // WHAT DO I DO HERE TO UN-REGISTER OLD ON-EXECUTE ACTION
    self.myDialog.on("execute", function() {
        console.log('Func2 called');
                self.myFunc2();
    });
},

myFunc1: function() {
 console.log('This is func1');
},

myFunc2: function() {
 console.log('This is func2');
}
}
```

On invoking `createDialog`, a `ConfirmDialog` gets created. It is initially configured to call `Func1` `on-execute`. The `Dialog` is then shown.

However, if the user does not do anything for 30 secs, the `on-execute` action gets changed to call `Func2`.

My problem is, when the user clicks after 30 secs, instead of just `Func2` getting called, both `Func1` and `Func2` gets called.

How do I **un-register** so that only `Func2` gets called if the execute happens after 30 secs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation "The return value of `on()` provides a method that can be used to remove the event listener from the event."

Ex:

```
require(["dojo/on", "dojo/_base/window"], function(on, win){
  var signal = on(win.doc, "click", function(){
    // remove listener after first event
    signal.remove();
    // do something else...
  });
});
```

so once function1 is called, you can use the handler (signal) to remove it.